# Angular Router nested named outlets

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I'm using Angular (v2.4.5). Is it possible to have nested named outlets?

Here is my situation:

```
//app.component.html
<router-outlet name="test"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

//dashboard.component.html
<router-outlet name="test"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Routes:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'inbox',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'inbox',
            component: InboxContentComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'test',
            component: TestComponent,
            outlet: 'test'
          }
       ],
       {
            path: 'test',
            component: TestComponent,
            outlet: 'test'
       }
    }
```

If I go to this url: `http://localhost/login(test:test)` the TestComponent is loaded in the `app.component.html` outlet.
If I go to this url: `http://localhost/dashboard/inbox(test:test)` the TestComponent is loaded in the `app.component.html` outlet and not in `dashboard.component.html`

I want to be able to target **test outlet from dashboard**. Is it possible?

Comment: So you're saying you have **two** router-outlets with the same name? I don't think it's allowed. Why don't you use different names and target just the name you need in the URL?

Comment: @AngularFrance thx for the fast response. I did that. I replaced test with test1 and I got this error: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test1'

Comment: Do you got the solution?

Comment: Have you tried with Angular 6?